# Is there any way to provide `html dom parser with two optional classes?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm curious if there is any way to provide two optional classes to `simple html dom parser`

```
<div class = 'a'>
   <!-- some data -->
<div>
<div class = 'b'>
   <!-- some data -->
<div>


<?php
  foreach($html->find('.a | .b') as $class){}

?>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's:

```
$html->find('.a,.b')
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
$html->find(div[class=a], div[class=b]);
```

as the doc states it uses jQuery type selectors.